# How do I sum columns with the same top row value efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array in the form:

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,1],
              [1,3,2],
              [1,3,2],
              [1,3,3]])
```

I want to sum all columns that have the same top row value so that I get the following result:

```py
res = np.array([[1,2],
                [3,3],
                [3,3],
                [4,3]])
```

I do something like

```py
sortedA = a[:,np.argsort(a[0])]
unique,count = np.unique(sortedA[0], return_index=True)
val = np.split(sortedA[1:,:].transpose(), count[1:])
agg = np.sum(val[0],axis=0)
for arr in val[1:]:
    agg = np.vstack((agg,np.sum(arr,axis=0)))
res = np.vstack((unique,agg.reshape(unique.shape[0],a.shape[1]-1).transpose()))
```

however it is suppperrr slow on large arrays (and I don't even know if it is 100% correct). What is a better way to do this? thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I understand what are you trying to achieve. Could you please show a desired output for `np.arange(1,10,1).reshape((3,3))` and `np.array(([1,1,1],[1,2,3],[1,4,5]))`?

Comment: The first row of the `res` array should be `[2,2]` no ?

Comment: @obchardon if it gives a faster result then sure `[2,2]` but I would like to preserve the first row if possible, so I can use it for indexing. But I can live without that requirement in the name of speed

Comment: @Suthiro for `np.arange(1,10,1).reshape((3,3))` it should return back `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and for `np.array(([1,1,1],[1,2,3],[1,4,5]))` it should return back `[[1],[6],[10]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works if you want your output in a list. The time needed is similar to the one in the previous answer.

```
solution=[np.sum(a[:,np.where(a[0,]==b)[0]],axis=1) for b in np.unique(a[0,])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that there are faster solutions using `numpy` magic like [`strides`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html), but I'm no guru. Also, as my experience shows, when one truly feels the need for speed, there is no escape from `Fortran / C++` anyway.

```
import numpy as np

# the input
a = np.array([[1,2,1],
              [1,3,2],
              [1,3,2],
              [1,3,3]])
# find unique indices along the 0th row
indices = np.unique(a[0,:])
# allocate some memory in shape
# number of indices X number of rows
b = np.zeros((len(indices),np.shape(a)[0]))
# counter
ii = 0
# iterate over indices
for ind in indices:
    # np.sum(a[1:,a[0,:]==ind],axis = 1)
    # sums elements column-wise starting from 1st row if the 0th row element is equal to ind
    # np.concatenate(([ind] ... )) adds the indice to the top and could be omitted
    b[ii] = np.concatenate(([ind],np.sum(a[1:,a[0,:]==ind],axis = 1)))
    # increment the counter
    ii+=1
# transpose the output, since np.sum returns a row, not a column    
b = b.transpose()
```

output

```
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 3.],
       [3., 3.],
       [4., 3.]])
```